# How to locate MVC3 Razor (.VBHTML) View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Looks like I'm missing something here and I can't figure it out what it is. I'm creating a MVC3 VB.NET application using VS2010 VB Web Project templates. I have removed all the (.aspx) views and created .VBHTML Razor view - named Index.vbhtml under the Home folder. The HomeContoller has the action Index. When I run the app I get the below error.

The view 'Index' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx

~/Views/Home/Index.ascx ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

Obviously the view engine can't locate the .vbhtml view. Can anyone please tell me how to enable this? The same setup works with .cshtml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you register Razor as a ViewEngine?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // ...
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine(("vb")));
}
```

Comment: I can't see the RezorViewEngine() in the intelliSense. MSDN says there is a RazorViewEngine class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg453829(v=vs.98).aspx. But I cannot see it in System.Web.Mvc.dll (using Reflector). Can you please tell me what I'm missing here? I'm using MVC3

Answer (score 0):

Since you removed all of the .aspx I am guessing that this application was not originally a Razor application?  Did you add the reference to Razor in the web config?

```
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Comment: Yes it wasn't originally a Razor application. It was a Visual Basic  ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application (ASPX). I can't see a template for  ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application (RAZOR) under Visual Basic. I also add the config entry you suggested, but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was my mistake. I haven't had the latest MVC3 installed and was screwing up everything. Thanks a lot. ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine(("vb"))); pointed me to the right direction. The version I was referencing didn't had the RazorViewEngine